# Importing rules in PMD

Tags: java, maven, static-analysis

We are implementing on our company static analysis code and we are trying PMD, I've read the documentation on PMD and found it unclear.

I added the following to my `pom.xml` the following plugin as described on the documentation.

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>rulesets/java/braces.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>rulesets/java/naming.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</reporting>
```

What I am not understanding is where do I know the locations of the rules sets and how do I create my own XML file with the rules sets I want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...the locations of the rules sets...

- Your extract from pom.xml shows that you are using version 3.7 of Apache's maven-pmd-plugin.
- Therefore the rulesets used by default will be specified within the Apache jar file **maven-pmd-plugin-3.7.jar** in your local Repository.
- The only ruleset used by default is named **Maven Ruleset**, and is defined within the jar in file *{Repository location}/maven-pmd-plugin-3.7/rulesets/maven.xml*.
- This is the relevant content of that file:

> ```
> <ruleset name="Maven Ruleset"
>   xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0 http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd"
>   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">
>   <!--
>     Customized PMD ruleset for Maven, see [0] for more information
>     [0] https://pmd.github.io/latest/customizing/howtomakearuleset.html
>   -->
>   <description>
>     This ruleset checks the code for discouraged programming constructs.
>   </description>
>   <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml"/>
>   <rule ref="rulesets/java/empty.xml">
>     <exclude name="EmptyCatchBlock"/>
>   </rule>
>   <rule ref="rulesets/java/empty.xml/EmptyCatchBlock">
>     <properties>
>       <property name="allowCommentedBlocks" value="true"/>
>     </properties>
>   </rule>
>   <rule ref="rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml"/>
>   <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml"/>
>   <rule ref="rulesets/java/imports.xml"/>
> </ruleset>
> ```

- That ruleset file refers to a number of other rulesets (e.g. **unusedcode.xml**), [each of which can be viewed on GitHub](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/tree/master/pmd-java/src/main/resources/rulesets/java).
- You can also [read a description of each ruleset file on PMD's web site](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/rules/index.html).
- Note that the information above specifically applies to your version of the plugin (3.7), but if you [refer to Apache's documentation for version 3.9](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html) things have changed slightly.

> ...how do I create my own xml file with the rules sets I want to
>   use?

[The plugin documentation by Apache describes that](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html), and also details how you can share a common set of rulesets between projects.